# TextBlock with a slider when text is too long in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

As in title. I want to create `TextBlock` with both horizontal and vertical sliders, that will automatically adjust depending on text size. Google just shows me `Slider` control which is definitely not what i'm looking for.

Any clues what can i use to achieve it?

Edit

Thanks to some of the helpful people here i have this:

```xml
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignScrollViewer}">
            <TextBlock ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="{Binding Path=(SQLLog:LogDisplay.LogAdvanced)}" FontSize="12"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Vertical scroll bar appears, horizontal not. Even when text doesn't fit inside the `TextBlock`.

Comment: Remove `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` from the `TextBlock` and add it to your `ScrollViewer`. If you want horizontal scrolling to be possible also apply a value for `Width` to the `TextBlock` that is at least as big as the `ScrollViewer`s `Width`.

Comment: Now it works fine. Linked example had it inside `TextBlock`. Alright, i believe problem is solved. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ScrollViewer` and its `HorizontalScrollBarVisiblity` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` properties. Just surround your `TextBox` with it:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Height="100"
              Width="200">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyFancyTextProperty}" 
               Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=Width}"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Consider adding `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to your `TextBlock`, so that its content doesn't end up being displayed in one line.

[image]

If you want to display the scrollbars at any time, even if the content fits, set their values to `Visible`:

```
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
```

Comment: Horizontal scroll does not appear, even though it's set to auto. I'm trying to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Edit your question and add the piece of code that doesn't work, so that we can help you. Hard to guess what you are doing. Normally you wouldn't need a horizontal scrollbar, if you let the content scroll vertically.